# How to fetch contact id in your iOS app?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, abpeoplepickerview, addressbookui

I am new to iOS and I have fetched contacts in my app, but how to fetch the contact id... suppose if there are two numbers saved with the same name, so how to fetch that particular contact name's id?

Comment: are you using ABAddressbook or Contacts framework, many method of ABAddressbook are deprecated in the iOS 9 ?

Comment: can you tell me the process for fetching contacts and contact ID using Contacts framework...i have used ABaddressbook framework, but its deprecated

Comment: are you using swift or objective- c?

Comment: i am using objective c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try like this :
import framework

```
#import <Contacts/Contacts.h>
```

Code

```
- (void) getContacts {
    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted == YES) {
            //keys with fetching properties
            NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
            NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
            NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
            } else {
                for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
                    //store all the contacts as per your requirement
                    NSLog(@"Id %@",contact.identifier);//the contact id which you want
                    NSLog(@"Name %@",contact.givenName);
                }
            }
        }        
    }];
}
```

Comment: @AmrutGaikwad Glad that it helps if this answer helps you to resolve your question please select answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: ok..can you also tell me how to add that fetched contact array to a table view?

Comment: provide the array index to cellForRowAtIndexPath method index and get data from particular object via key

Comment: cell.textLabel.text=[[_ContactsCN objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]givenName];
            [_table reloadData];

Comment: here above is my code for table view- cellForRowAtIndexPath method,...._ContactCN is my array and givenName is the key....but i am still not able to display the table..plz help me

Comment: try cell.textLabel.text = [_ContactsCN[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"givenName"] also you don't need '[_table reloadData];' inside cellForRow

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i am still not able to display data on tableview, i tried every other possibility, but my table view is blank.

Comment: did you set the delegates of the tableview?

Comment: and i also added the cnContacts array to my  _ContactsCN array using add object